# How to get client IP address(es)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, ip

We have an asp.net application which deployed in head office of a bank. Employees of the bank are consumers of this application.

Employees of the bank are usually access this application using their computers which is connected to internet though a proxy server.

For auditing purpose we need all (at least one) ip-address assigned to their LAN-interface, when they login to the application.

I know there are some Server Variables which provides IP of client but they are only giving us IP of Proxy Server (external IP).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Client IP using just Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript)

Comment: its not that question is regarding the public ip address (external ip address) i am looking for internal machine ip address (LAN)

Comment: There is a link there that shows some ideas: http://www.gnucitizen.org/blog/javascript-address-info/  However, it does not work equally across all browsers.  You generally don't have access to that OS-level information from Javascript.

Comment: Thanks @Joe: a very informative article.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the proxy but I believe the standard is to put the original client IP under the server variable called HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR. Sometimes others are used HTTP_X_FORWARDED and HTTP_CLIENT_IP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946538/getting-client-values-of-iis-server-variables-in-load-balanced-environment